# How should I unit test Spring, Hibernate and Struts using junit

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit, struts

What is the best practice? How should I implement it so that the database isn't polluted?

Comment: this is about integration testing, not unit testing.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing#Testing_Levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform integration tests on code that accesses database, you may benefit from using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html). DBUnit can load test data into the database before each test. This can help you compare the result of the test case against an expected set of values.

Answer (score 3):

[This blogpost of mine](http://bozhobg.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/database-integration-testing-with-spring-jpa-junit-and-maven/) describes a process of unit-testing using spring, hibernate and maven. The maven part can be substituted with your particular build facilities.

Тesting Struts (not Structs, I guess) depends on your struts/spring integration. Anyway take a look at [StrutsTestCase](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net/) and [this article about StrutsUT](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/09/22/test-struts.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I find your blog too general.

Comment: it is quite concrete, I think. These are the exact steps I take when testing a spring app.

Answer (score 2):

For Hibernate unit testing you can use HSQL DB :

> Unit-testing should have as few
>   barriers as possible. For relational
>   databases those barriers range from
>   external dependencies (is the database
>   running?) to speed to keeping the
>   relational schema synchronized with
>   your object model. For these reasons
>   it is vital to keep database access
>   code away from the core object model
>   and to test as much as possible
>   without touching a real database.

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=UnitTesting